# How to know what selector is queried in jQuery $([CSS Selectors]) method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm scraping a web page to extract content related to specific CSSselector like this:

```
$("p, h1, h2").each(function(index) {
   // Do stuff
})
```

Now, I'd like to know what selector corresponds to the returned object: I'd like to know if it is a `p` tag, an `h1` tag or an `h2` tag.

How can I achieve that? Here is the idea:

```
$("p, h1, h2").each(function(index) {
   console.log("CSS Selector: ", $(this).cssSelectorName)
})
```

Comment: look at the [tagName property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName), eg `this.tagName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) you can write:

```
$("p, h1, h2").each(function(index, ele) {
    console.log("CSS Selector: ", ele.tagName);
})
```

A different approach can be based on [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```js
$("p, h1, h2").each(function(index, ele) {
    console.log("CSS Selector: ", ele.tagName.toLowerCase());
    if ($(ele).is('p')) {
        console.log('This is a paragraph')
    } else {
        if ($(ele).is('h1')) {
            console.log('This is heading 1')
        } else {
            if ($(ele).is('h2')) {
                console.log('This is heading 2')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
    in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
    passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
    PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get the selector. But since you're selecting by tag name, you can get that.

```
$("p, h1, h2").each(function() {
   console.log("CSS Selector: ", this.tagName)
});
```

If you were selecting by classes, you could test that:

```
$(".class1, .class2").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("class1")) {
        console.log("class1");
    } else {
        console.log("class2");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your selectors are only tag names or only classes you can follow @gaetanoM or @Brmar 's answers, but if you will be using more complicated selectors you can use the code below

```
var selector = "p.first, h1, h2, p#amazing";
var selectors = selector.split(', ');
var jqObject = $(selector);

jqObject.each(function(index, el) {
    selectors.forEach(function(sel, i) {
        if (el.matches(sel)) {
            console.log(el, 'matching', sel);
        };
    });
});
```

the only thing to watch out here is that in your selector string all selectors has to be separated by a comma-space `,`. As you can see from the code you get your jquery object with elements inside and iterate over them, inside each iteration you check if the element is matching any of the selectors from the array of selectors and if it matches log out the element, the word `matching` and the selector. `.matches()` comes well handy in this scenario.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/antonk52/pen/VWKXxg)